# SQL query runs, but not producing any results

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a following query to display Student data in dataGridView, but it doest seems to display any records at all. My code:

```
public void setSQL()
{
    string ConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\jasper\\Desktop\\AutoReg\\AutoReg.accdb;";

    OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr);
    MyConn.Open();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //query to ask
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Student";

    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, MyConn))
    {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
        {
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            MyConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some advice: use try and catch blocks so that you can close your connection if querying fails (it may do so for reasons outside your control).

Comment: Obvious, but make sure you're hitting the right file and that it has data in the student table.

Comment: This is the right file, and I'm certain that there is some data in it

Comment: When you are using connection less oriented architecture, you don't need to close the connection..  And its always better idea to keep your database code under `using` statements.. For more information about DataSet : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit:** After seeing the comment I noticed my error. I was assuming a web application.

You should use a `DataTable` as a data source, not a `DataSet`. Set the data source property to the first table in the DataSet's tables collection.

In truth, you can use a DataSet, but it's not so straightforward. It does allow the user to change the table she's seeing, though.

Comment: does not seem to work :/
'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind'

Comment: Can't believe an accepted answer, with downvote. @jaspernorth: Please accept this answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can check.

1. Are you sure you have entries in this table?
2. Try commenting out the part about the OleDbDataAdapter, use a DataReader instead so you can step through and see if there are rows being returned.
3. if you are getting rows in your datareader, then it may have to do with your datagrid set up.  Are you using autogenerate columns?  If not, are the columns set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
```

Try this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```